Issue building APK with EAS - Gradle Error on Line 66
I'm facing an issue while trying to build my APK using EAS. The build breaks in the cloud with the following error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
Script 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\SpreadApp\node_modules\expo-modules-autolinking\scripts\android\autolinking_implementation.gradle' line: 66
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'SpreadApp'.

No such property: url for class: java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry
Possible solutions: key

I've tried updating all my dependencies, cleaning the cache, and checking the build.gradle configuration, but the issue persists. Any guidance on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated!
